# Need help studying the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})}$

I tried cauchy's condensation but I don't think its right since I don't know if the sequence from the series is descending

Any ideas?

Comment: Start with determining what $\sin \frac{\pi n}{2}$ is.

Comment: i don't get it..

Comment: There's a pattern to detect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
sin(n\frac{\pi}{2}) = 1  \qquad \text {for $n = 4k + 1$ } 
$$
$$
sin(n\frac{\pi}{2}) = -1  \qquad \text {for $n = 4k + 3$ } 
$$
$$
sin(n\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0  \qquad \text {otherwise.} 
$$
So your series is just

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}
$$
and this converges since it is alternating and decreasing to zero.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin n\pi /2=0$ when $n$ is even and $\sin n \pi /2=(-1)^{(n-1)/2}$ when $n$ is odd. So put $n=2k-1$ in the summation, with $k\in \mathbb N$ (because any term $(1/n)\sin n\pi /2$ is equal to $0$ when $n=2k$ is even.) And we have $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac {(-1)^{(k-1)/2}}{2k-1}=1-1/3+1/5-1/7+...,$ an alternating series with terms whose absolute values decrease to $0.$

BTW the sum of the series is $\pi /4.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=\frac{\sin( \frac{n\pi}{2})}{n}$

and $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$.

we have for each $k\geq 1$,

$$a_{4k-3}=1$$

$$a_{4k-2}=0$$

$$a_{4k-1}=-1$$

and

$$a_{4k}=0.$$

thus for each $n\geq 1$,

$$S_{4n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (\frac{1}{4k-3}-\frac{1}{4k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{(4k-3)(4k-1)}$$

this shows that $S_{4n}$ has a limit since it is the partial sum of a convergent Riemann series.

The same approach can be used for the other partial sums.